# Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo (App keeps stopping)

Tags: android

I am getting error"Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo" when I run the app and app keep crashing.Code is pretty same as much as tutorial.I really don't know how to solve this problem.If any of you know about this problem, please spare me some ideas.The code about user sign in and retrieving token from rails server.Here is the code.

```
#Main Activity
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://teamdronex.com/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());

    Retrofit retrofit = builder.build();
    UserClient userClient = retrofit.create(UserClient.class);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        findViewById(R.id.btn_login).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.btn_secret).setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.btn_login:
                login();
                break;
            case R.id.btn_secret:
                getSecret();
                break;
        }

    }

    private static String token;

    private void login() {
        Login login = new Login("johndoe@example.com", "aaaaaa");
        Call<User> call = userClient.login(login);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<User>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<User> call, Response<User> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, response.body().getToken(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    token = response.body().getToken();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "login not correct", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<User> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    private void getSecret() {
        Call<ResponseBody> call = userClient.getSecret(token);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    try {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, response.body().string(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "token is not correct", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
    }


}

#UserClient

public abstract class UserClient {
@POST("sign_in")
abstract Call<User> login(@Body Login login);

@GET("secretinfo")
abstract Call<ResponseBody> getSecret(@Header("Authorization") String authToken);
```

}

```
#Manifest.xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.login_retro">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".Api.model.MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>

#Logcat Error


at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2548)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: API declarations must be interfaces.
    at retrofit2.Utils.validateServiceInterface(Utils.java:309)
    at retrofit2.Retrofit.create(Retrofit.java:128)
    at com.example.login_retro.Api.model.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:27)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1078)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2538)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: baseUrl must end in /: https://teamdronex.com/users/sign_in`

Comment: I changed baseUrl to( https:/teamdronex.com) and this error disappeared . But other errors appeared again "Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: API declarations must be interfaces".

Comment: Show your UserClient class

Comment: I added the UserClient , take a look in code session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem:** You must define your HTTP API in a Java interface instead of a Java abstract class.

**Solution:** Change `UserClient` from

```
public abstract class UserClient {

    @POST("sign_in")
    abstract Call<User> login(@Body Login login);

    @GET("secretinfo")
    abstract Call<ResponseBody> getSecret(@Header("Authorization") String authToken);
}
```

to

```
public interface UserClient {

    @POST("sign_in")
    Call<User> login(@Body Login login);

    @GET("secretinfo")
    Call<ResponseBody> getSecret(@Header("Authorization") String authToken);
}
```